# how to fix error Convert.toInt(txtnum.Text)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do math with textbox, I tried to convert it integer  `Convert.toInt(txtnum.Text)`, but when I run the code it give me invalid format input string. How can I get around this error.

Comment: What is that you're trying to convert? Btw, when dealing with this kind of input, use `Int32.TryParse()`. The text must represent an Integer (1, -1), using the current culture format (and position) for the negative sign, if any.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to convert it integer Convert.toInt(txtnum.Text), but when i
>   run the code it give me invalid formate input string.

That occurs if the string you are trying to convert is not a valid number.  For instance, if "duck" was in the TextBox, then it will give this error.  It will also fail if the textbox is **blank**.

You can trap these kinds of errors using [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__), like this:

```
Dim value As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(txtnum.Text, value) Then

     ' ... do something with "value" in here ...

     Debug.Print("Value = " & value)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input: " & txtnum.Text, "Invalid Integer")
End If
```